# Copy/pasting slide from template PPT to current location in open PPT

Tags: vba, powerpoint, copy-paste

I'm trying to put together a macro so that, when I run it, it copy/pastes a slide from a template presentation to *after the current slide* within the active presentation. I'm 90% of the way there, but can't seem to figure out how to make the paste portion function as desired. All I can find is how to paste it at a specified location (e.g., slide 4), or at the end of the presentation.

This is the MS resource I've referred to so far: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides.paste

This is the current version of my code:

```
  Sub PastefromTemplate()
  Dim tgt, i%

  'open the target presentation
  'use path with the file if it is in a different location
  Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open("source path")

  'copy slide 1 from source presentation
  'change the item number in order to target a different slide
  objPresentation.Slides.Item(1).Copy
 
  'paste the slide in target, currently set to slide 3
  tgt = Array(3)
  Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Paste tgt i

  objPresentation.Close
  End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Determining what the current slide is?  Or something else?

Comment: The thing I'm butting up against is the limitation of the Slide.Paste method.  From the MS VBA resource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides.paste), it looks like the only options are to either A) input a slide number for the target location; or B) let it default to pasting at the end of the presentation.

I'm admittedly new to PPT VBA, so I'm not sure whether a workaround to this problem exists.

Comment: As an update, I found two resources that might be helpful in figuring this out -- but I've tried to incorporate them into the code above, and have not had any luck yet:

1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides.findbyslideid and

2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.slideindex

I think that one of these can be nested in the Slides.Paste method to return the current slide number, but I'm not certain what the correct approach would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, was finally able to figure it out:

```
Sub Slide9()
Dim src As Presentation
Dim trg As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim target As Presentation

'Copies slide (change # in Item(#)) from the source presentation
Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open("source file path")
objPresentation.Slides.Item(9).Copy
 
'Closes the source presentation
objPresentation.Close

'Go back to active presentation and paste, then go to pasted slide
With ActiveWindow.View
.Paste
.GotoSlide (ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex)
End With
        
End Sub
```